# Computing Cartesian product of two sequences in Factor

Tags: cartesian-product, factor-lang

I'm just starting to dabble in [Factor](http://factorcode.org). I want to compute the Cartesian product of two sequences:

```
{ 1 2 3 }
{ 8 9 }
```

What I want to see is a sequence of sequences:

```
{ { 1 8 } { 1 9 } { 2 8 } { 2 9 } { 3 8 } { 3 9 } }
```

When I use the `cartesian-product` word, I get a sequence of sequences of sequences:

```
{ { { 1 8 } { 1 9 } } { { 2 8 } { 2 9 } } { { 3 8 } { 3 9 } } }
```

I've also tried `[ 2array ] cartesian-map`, but I get the same thing. Finally, I attempted `[ 2array ] cartesian-each`, but I get each pair pushed separately on the stack. At least it's flat, but I want them all in one array.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there's an existing library method that does this (just getting started myself), but you can do it by composing [`cartesian-product`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-cartesian-product,sequences.html) with [`append`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-append%2Csequences.html) and [`reduce`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-reduce%2Csequences.html) :

```
--- Data stack:
{ "a" "b" "c" }
{ 1 2 3 4 } 
( scratchpad ) cartesian-product { } [ append ] reduce .
{
    { "a" 1 }
    { "a" 2 }
    { "a" 3 }
    { "a" 4 }
    { "b" 1 }
    { "b" 2 }
    { "b" 3 }
    { "b" 4 }
    { "c" 1 }
    { "c" 2 }
    { "c" 3 }
    { "c" 4 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatten1` from `sequences.extras`:

```
IN: scratchpad { 1 2 3 } { 8 9 } cartesian-product flatten1 .
{ { 1 8 } { 1 9 } { 2 8 } { 2 9 } { 3 8 } { 3 9 } }
```